# Deprecating classes and function in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, deprecated

I am working on a project in C++ where I have written a set of new classes which supersedes some other classes with similar functionality. I therefore want to deprecate the old classes and all methods within it. I've found you can do `[[deprecated]]` or `[[deprecated](reason for deprecation)]` but this only for C++14. I'm using C++11 but surely deprecating something its a new thing that only the latest C++ versions can do?

Am I missing something or would I have to upgrade my project to be C++14 (assuming I have a compiler that is capable)?

Comment: Deprecating isn't new, but the attribute is. You might want to look into compiler attributes/pragmas if you want it before C++14.

Comment: There are some compiler-dependent solutions. What's your compiler? Also, why not simply use a newer standard?

Comment: I would think in 2018 most compilers that support `C++11` should support `C++14`, so I would check that first.

Comment: Check your compiler's documentation. Even pre-dating C++11, most compilers have compiler-specific keywords that will result in a warning diagnostic if an attempt is made to reference a deprecated function or class. Since you neglected to specify which compiler you're using, no further help can be given.

Comment: I use a combo of VS 2017 for Windows and G++ for Linux. I've updated to use C++14 seems to be OK